# Duplicate question got an answer in comments -- I would like to accept it

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996434/does-readlines-read-the-whole-file-or-the-rest-of-the-file) that quite quickly was closed as a duplicate. I could see the reasoning behind the close vote, but I expressed that I disagreed in the comments and I asked the person that closed the question to reconsider.

After the question was closed, a commentator gave me the kind of answer I was looking for (which was not available in the duplicate questions). Ideally I would like to remove the duplicate lock so he can post his comment as an answer. Could I have some additional thoughts on the situation? Should I just leave the question as-is?

Comment: Then once it gets reopened reply to their comment suggesting they write an answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I had not seen the reopen link. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, if their answer would answer the duplicate, suggest they write it there.

Comment: You've got to love the irony of this being marked as a duplicate.